# How to loop through cell values?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am stuck at looping through cell values.

It's about forming a Word file by exporting data from Excel file with VBA.

I want to loop through certain cells (Ax ~ Ay) and export the texts in those cells to Word.

```vb
wDoc.Content.InsertAfter Range("A1")
wDoc.Content.InsertAfter Range("A2")
wDoc.Content.InsertAfter Range("A3")
```

I want to loop through cell A1~ max.

I think the loop is similar with other types for loop, but I can't think how to change only the numerical part of the cell in the for loop.

First I thought it would be similar to assigning variables to the numerical part of the cell, and then use "for" however, it doesn't work as I guess I assigned the cell with "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a loop from 1 to 3 (according the row numbers you want to loop through

```
Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 1 To 3
    wDoc.Content.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Value
Next iRow
```

Note that you should never use a `Range` without specifying in which workbook and worksheet it is supposed to be.

Comment: ... or use the `Cells`-Property: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1)` or `.Cells(iRow, "A")`

Comment: @FunThomas Actually I didn't want to change the command to keep it more obvious to the OP how to solve such kind of problems but yes, I would prefer `cells` too in that case, even I think it is just a matter of code design. Or is there a computational advantage of `.Cells(iRow, "A")` over `.Range("A" & iRow)` I'm not aware of (just for my interest)?

Comment: In this case, it really doesn't matter. But yes, I always prefer `Cells(row, "A")` to `.Cells(row, 1)`. Imagine trying to visually see what column does `.Cells(row, 1045)` refer to? :D But in general the `Range` function is far more powerful than using `Cells`. It lets you reference either a single cell, or a specific range of cells, all at once. `Range(Cells(r1,c1),Cells(r2,c2))`.

Comment: No real advantage. You need string concatenation to get the range address and in the background Excel needs to separate this address back to a row and a column number, but the overhead is so small that I doubt that you can measure it.